# Warning: odbc_execute(): Not enough parameters (2 should be 3) given in

Tags: php, sql, odbc, prepared-statement

We are seeing this warning show up seemingly randomly.

Just to prove that it's 'random' I wrote a super simple php file for run the same exact SQL prepared statement 1000 times. In that run we got the error twice. Here is the code:

```
<?php

//SQL Connection stuff would be here

for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tags WHERE fk_userTagged = ? AND tagsID > ?';
    $statement = odbc_prepare($dbc,$sql);
    odbc_execute($statement,[638,5]);

    //grab one row
    $row = odbc_fetch_array($statement);
    echo $i . ': ' . $row['tagsID'];
    echo '<br/>';
}

?>
```

In the last loop, iteration 410 and 466 threw the warning. Each time it's different. Sometimes it won't happen in the 1000 loops, sometimes it will happen about a dozen times.